# os.path.exists on Windows sometimes succeeds and sometimes fails for mapped network drive

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Python 3.6.8 64 bit on Windows 10. I have a network drive mapped to `Z:\`.

When I launch the following through the CMD, it prints `True`:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.path.exists(r\"Z:\<directory>\file.txt\"))"
```

However, when the exact same command is run in a Python script launched by a different user (user used by the Gitlab runner), the command returns `False`.

Any ideas?

Comment: does the user in the Gitlab Runner have the same rights that your user in the command line has?

Comment: Does the different user have correct rights on the share? (Rights on the file are not enough on network shares. Rights on the share itself are also required.) Also, in general don't use `os.path.exists()` at all. It's completely unnecessary

Comment: Change the command to `python -c "import os; print(os.stat(r\"\\<unc_address>\<directory>\file.txt\"))"`. The exception should provide more information.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, it seems both of the users have the same rights over the mapped network drive and the file.
I checked it like so: right click on network drive > properties > security > advanced > effective access > type in the name of the problematic user > see that it has rights to list folder / read data and read attributes. I guess these are the needed rights?

Comment: @ErykSun I get the following output: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: Z:\\dirA\\dirB`

Comment: @AvivCohn No, those are just the file system rights. Check the permission on the share itself. There is a separate permissions dialog in the same place where you can define the network share name. This is the relevant one.

Comment: @Tomalak Hmmm, sorry, I can't find what you're referring to. By the way, I'm now trying to use a mapped network drive `Z:\`. So when right clicking on it > Properties, I don't see a "sharing" dialog or tab (as suggested by Google). Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, still not the right place. When you share a folder using Folder Properties, Sharing tab, Advanced Sharing, *there* is a Permissions dialog. This is the relevant one.

Comment: It is not a permission error. `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3) could mean that the mapped drive "Z:" isn't defined for the current user's logon session (which you neglected to include in the original question), or that there's a problem with the underlying UNC path of the mapped drive "Z:" -- which could be a directory in the path that's not found or maybe the redirector isn't started -- or that "dirA" isn't found. Apparently "file.txt" is actually "dirB" (please try to use consistent examples), but if "dirB" was the immediate problem, the error would be `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2) instead.

Comment: @ErykSun I see. Thank you for your time (the question actually started when I was trying to simply use a UNC path, I later changed to a mapped network drive and edited the question accordingly).
I am certain that the above command works for a user which is a local admin for the machine running the command. However, it fails for a different user which is not an admin. So it's for sure something to do with the users.

Comment: The most likely reason is simply that the mapped drive "Z:" isn't defined for the Gitlab runner user's logon session. Use the UNC path instead of the mapped drive. Then this could become a permission error issue if the Gitlab runner user doesn't have access to the UNC path because custom credentials were used for the session user's mapped drive "Z:" or via the session user's credential vault.

Comment: @ErykSun Can you point me in the direction of how I can fix this? I.e., how can I make the Z: drive defined also for the Gitlab runner user's logon session?

Comment: You could simply use the subprocess module to run `net use`, or you could use PyWin32 or ctypes to call the Windows API directly. I'd try `net use` first.

Comment: @ErykSyb I'm looking for the simplest solution that will allow the Python script started by the GItlab runner to read files from the given UNC path. A mapped network drive isn't needed as far as I'm converned. Do you think it should be simpler to read directly from the UNC path, without a mapped network drive?
If so, as described in my original question, a bare UNC path failed as well. So I suppose that was a permissions issue. In order to solve the permissions issue, do I need access to the machine hosting the directory the network drive is mapped to?

Comment: Please check the UNC path with `os.stat`, as I suggested for the original version of your question, before getting sidelined into the mapped drive discussion. If there's a permission issue, it should raise a `PermissionError` with winerror `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) or `ERROR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED` (65).